# The column subtotal of a matrix doesn't show properly

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax

[image]I have a matrix where I want to see the subtotal of every row (in the right corner). When I put the column subtotal it doesn't show the number.

I have three metrics in the columns with the following formula:

```
MedidaSelecc_anyo_actual = 
  IF(HASONEVALUE(MedidaSelecc_CareVisit[Medida]),
    SWITCH(VALUES(MedidaSelecc_CareVisit[Medida]),
      "Care Visit", [# care visit_sin_zeros],
      "Ventas", [Ventas (sin 0)]
    )
  )

MedidaSelecc_anyo_anterior = 
  IF(HASONEVALUE(MedidaSelecc_CareVisit[Medida]),
    SWITCH(VALUES(MedidaSelecc_CareVisit[Medida]),
      "Care Visit", [Care visits periodo anterior],
      "Ventas", [Ventas periodo anterior (sin 0)]
    )
  )

MedidaSelecc_dif_anyos = 
  IF(HASONEVALUE(MedidaSelecc_CareVisit[Medida]),
    SWITCH(VALUES(MedidaSelecc_CareVisit[Medida]),
      "Care Visit", [% care visit dif periodo anterior],
      "Ventas", [% ventas dif periodo anterior]
    )
  )
```

And the metrics have the following formulas:

```
# care visit_sin_zeros = 
  if(or(isblank([# care visit]),[# care visit] == 0),
    blank(),
    //Fixed([# care visit],0,TRUE)
    FORMAT([# care visit], "##,0")
  )

Ventas (sin 0) =
  IF(OR(ISBLANK([Ventas]), [Ventas] = 0),
    BLANK(),
    FORMAT([Ventas], "#,### €")
)

Care visits periodo anterior = 
  VAR ano_actual = SELECTEDVALUE('Calendar'[mars_year])
  VAR periodo = SELECTEDVALUE('Calendar'[period])
  VAR ano_anterior = ano_actual - 1
  VAR fecha_actual_terminada = IF(TODAY() >= MAXX(FILTER('Calendar', 'Calendar'[period] = periodo), DATEVALUE('Calendar'[Fecha])), 1, 0)
  RETURN
    IF(fecha_actual_terminada = 1, CALCULATE([# care visit],ALL('Calendar'), 'Calendar'[mars_year] = ano_anterior,'Calendar'[period] = periodo))

Ventas periodo anterior (sin 0) =
  IF(OR(ISBLANK([Ventas periodo anterior]), [Ventas periodo anterior] = 0),
    BLANK(),
    FORMAT([Ventas periodo anterior], "#,### €")
  )

% care visit dif periodo anterior = 
  IF([# care visit] = 0,
    BLANK(),
    IF([Care visits periodo anterior] = 0,
      BLANK(),
      ([# care visit] - [Care visits periodo anterior]) / [Care visits periodo anterior]
    )
  )

% ventas dif periodo anterior =
  IF([Ventas] = 0,
    BLANK(),
    IF([Ventas periodo anterior] = 0,
      BLANK(),
      ([Ventas] - [Ventas periodo anterior]) / [Ventas periodo anterior]
    )
  )
```

The column "MedidaSelecc_anyo_actual" does show the result properly but the other two columns doesn't. How can I fix this?

```
# care visit = 
var res = [# care visit servicios no hospitalizados] + [# care visit servicios hopitalizados]
RETURN
SWITCH(res,0,blank(),res)

# care visit servicios no hospitalizados = 

    var res = 
        CALCULATE(
            DISTINCTCOUNT('fact_venta'[id_servicio_centro]),
            FILTER(fact_venta, fact_venta[es_servicio_hospitalizado] = 0),     //id_familia = hospitalizados 
            FILTER('fact_venta', fact_venta[intangible_tangible] = "Intangible")
        ) 
    
    return IF(res, res, 0)

# care visit servicios hopitalizados = 

var res = SUMX(tbl_carevisit_hospitalizados, tbl_carevisit_hospitalizados[flag_agrupar_servicios_contiguos])

return IF(res, res, 0)
```

[image]

Thank you!

PD: Sorry for my english, is not my first language.

Comment: Can you share a snip of your Matrix visual please with the rows, columns, and values, used please. At first glance, some of your measures are returning a string instead of number. Another issue could be `HASONEVALUE` - will need to see your matrix to see if this is an issue, as for totals there maybe more than one value.

Comment: I've just edited the post with a image of the matrix. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to totals, there won't be a `SELECTEDVALUE` for that column/row dimension. In this case, the Total on the right won't have a `'Calendar'[period]`. So this measure is the issue:

```
Care visits periodo anterior = 
  VAR ano_actual = SELECTEDVALUE('Calendar'[mars_year])
  VAR periodo = SELECTEDVALUE('Calendar'[period])
  VAR ano_anterior = ano_actual - 1
  VAR fecha_actual_terminada = IF(TODAY() >= MAXX(FILTER('Calendar', 'Calendar'[period] = periodo), DATEVALUE('Calendar'[Fecha])), 1, 0)
  RETURN
    IF(fecha_actual_terminada = 1, CALCULATE([# care visit],ALL('Calendar'), 'Calendar'[mars_year] = ano_anterior,'Calendar'[period] = periodo))
```

Specifically this line:

```
   VAR periodo = SELECTEDVALUE('Calendar'[period])
```

I think you can simply use the following:

```
Care visits periodo anterior =
  CALCULATE(
    [# care visit],
    SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Calendar'[Fecha])
  )
```

Comment: If I do what you suggest, I see the subtotal correctly, but I also see the subtotal in each column as well, in the period column. For example, in the first row, there is a 68.079,76€ in every "Año anterior" column, the same amount which is the total. How can I fix it?Thank you!

Comment: Could you share the DAX for `[# care visit]`. And could you share a new snip showing the issue, please.

Comment: I've just added the dax for # care visit and a snip. Thank you!

Comment: Updated the answer above.

Comment: Did this answer your question?